# Why can't I create a managed device on Intune?

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, intune

I am trying to create a managed device in Intune but I am getting different errors.

This is the documentation I am using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_devices_manageddevice_create.

I am testing the functionality using Graph Explorer so I do not need the authorization token and the account I am logged into is the global administrator and has the appropriate delegated permission enabled 'DeviceManagementManagedDevices.ReadWrite.All'.

When I try the first request  `/users/{usersId}/managedDevices` I get a 403

`An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

If I try `/deviceManagement/managedDevices` I get 400

`No OData route exists that match template`

I am signed up for a free trail for Intune and Azure AD if this makes any difference.

What could I be missing?

The request body I based off the example in the documentation for create managedDevice. I also tried removing the odata type but it makes no difference.

An example I have tried

```
 {
        "id": "5h5b3fab-0169-45de-9aad-3d928ebbe1a0",
        "userId": null,
        "deviceName": "newIntuneDev",
        "deviceActionResults": [],
        "enrolledDateTime": "2018-02-19T11:04:24.242385Z",
        "lastSyncDateTime": "2018-01-03T14:01:45.1553437Z",
        "operatingSystem": "Android",
        "complianceState": "compliant",
        "jailBroken": "false",
        "managementAgent": "mdm",
        "osVersion": "7.0",
        "easActivated": true,
        "easDeviceId": "DFC17B28459230B3",
        "easActivationDateTime": "2018-01-19T11:05:11.4483412Z",
        "azureADRegistered": true,
        "deviceEnrollmentType": "userEnrollment",
        "activationLockBypassCode": null,
        "emailAddress": null,
        "azureADDeviceId": "89f65205-72af-4830-a9b1-ebcd3160476f",
        "deviceRegistrationState": "registered",
        "deviceCategoryDisplayName": null,
        "isSupervised": false,
        "exchangeLastSuccessfulSyncDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "exchangeAccessState": "none",
        "exchangeAccessStateReason": "none",
        "remoteAssistanceSessionUrl": "",
        "remoteAssistanceSessionErrorDetails": "",
        "isEncrypted": false,
        "userPrincipalName": null,
        "model": "SM-G930F",
        "manufacturer": "samsung",
        "imei": "539467078998547",
        "complianceGracePeriodExpirationDateTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
        "serialNumber": "T58H52RP9KN",
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "androidSecurityPatchLevel": "2018-01-01",
        "userDisplayName": null,
        "configurationManagerClientEnabledFeatures": {
            "inventory": false,
            "modernApps": false,
            "resourceAccess": false,
            "deviceConfiguration": false,
            "compliancePolicy": false,
            "windowsUpdateForBusiness": false
        },
        "wiFiMacAddress": "4C6641183631",
        "deviceHealthAttestationState": null,
        "subscriberCarrier": "",
        "meid": "659467078998547",
        "totalStorageSpaceInBytes": 0,
        "freeStorageSpaceInBytes": 0,
        "managedDeviceName": "newDevice",
        "partnerReportedThreatState": "unknown"
    }
```

Comment: Did you use a Guest account to login Graph Explorer ?

Comment: I logged in using a member of the Directory with the directory role as Global administrator. I have also tried with another member of the directory with administrator privileges but still get the same errors.

Comment: I can get the devices which requires the same delegated permission but cannot create one.

Comment: Could you post your request body in the question?

Comment: It seems that you may post incorrect body in request body.Refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_devices_manageddevice_create#request-body) to post request body. **DON'T** copy the request body from the example to your body.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I have added in an example body I used and it contains the appropriate properties as stated in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_devices_manageddevice_create) is a documentation error. API does not support creation of managedDevice. You would need to MDM enroll a device into Intune to see data populated under ~/managedDevices API.

1. Signup for a free Intune trial subscription
2. Set MDM authority - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/mdm-authority-set
3. Enroll a device -
   https://www.microsoft.com/itshowcase/Article/Video/634/Enroll-your-mobile-device-in-Microsoft-Intune-for-corporate-access
4. Once successfully enrolled, device should show up under ~/managedDevices

Thanks,
Alemeshet Alemu - MSFT

Comment: Adding to the answer here, the Issue has been reported to the appropriate docs team who are investigating and will update it soon